# Min(IEnumerable<Double>) vs Min<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, type-parameter

Say I have a `List<double>` called `nums`. If I want to get the minimum of `nums`, which is a sequence of `double`s, I have two options:

1. use [`Min(IEnumerable<Double>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min) -- i.e. do `double minNum = nums.Min();`
2. use [`Min<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min) -- i.e. do `double minNums = nums.Min<double>();`

What's the difference? Why does C# offer both of these options instead of just offering just the generic version?

Comment: More efficient probably. Also special handling for NaN, see the source code https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Min.cs

Comment: The non-generic version avoids the overhead of using a comparer.